# How to retain paragraph indenting when using tex4ebook?

Tags: tex4ebook

My MWE renders a PDF with two paragraphs with indents and no spacing between paragraphs, which is what I want

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

However, when I generate an epub with `tex4ebook main.tex`, I'm getting no indents and spaces between paragraphs on some readers, like this:

[image]

I'm using the memoir class, so tried `\setlength{\parindent}{2em}` but none of my attempts have retained indenting after the tex4ebook conversion to epub.

Looking at the epub file, the html class for the first para is `noindent` and the second is `indent` which is what I want, but the css files has the line `p.indent{text-indent:0;}`. When I change this to `p.indent{text-indent:1.5em;}` I get the indent that I'm looking for. Also, if I delete the line `p + p{margin-top:1em;}` from the css, I get rid of the space between paragraphs.

Is there a way to get these css changes by changing my LaTeX code? Or maybe changing my tex4ebook cfg file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is quite easy, use the `p-indent` option:

```
$ make4ht filename.tex "p-indent"
```

You can read about most of TeX4ht options [here](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html#-texht-options1), they are the easiest way to change some default values.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: Usage with `tex4ebook` is similarly: `tex4ebook filename.tex p-indent`

Comment: @clel yes, `tex4ebook` supports most of options that work for HTML in TeX4ht.